# Find r such that $|2z|=|1+z^2|=2r$

Tags: complex-numbers

Find all $r>0$ real numbers, so that there exists a complex number $z$ such that $|2z|=|1+z^2|=2r$.

The progress I've made is:
\begin{align} 
\left(|z+i|^2 - 2\right) \left(|z-i|^2-2\right) & \;=\; 0 \ 
\end{align}
By squaring the equality and using $|z_1 + z_2 |^2 = (z_1 + z_2)\overline{(z_1 + z_2)}$.
I am stuck here!

Comment: Let $z=x+iy$ and see if you can't recover the equation$$x^4-2x^2+y^4-6y^2+2x^2y^2+1=0$$

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{C}$ is a field, so from $$ 
\left(|z+i|^2 - 2\right) \left(|z-i|^2-2\right)=0$$

we deduce either $|z+i|^2 - 2=0$ or $|z-i|^2 -2=0$.

If $|z+i|^2 - 2=0$, we have that $|z+i|^2=2$, that is, $z$ is in the circle of center $-i$ and radius $\sqrt{2}$.

Calling $z=x+iy$ and translating this to a $\mathbb{R}^2$ problem, we get $x^2+(y+1)^2=2$, so $$x^2+y^2=2-2y-1=1-2y,$$

and $x^2+y^2$ is minimum when $y$ is maximum, that is, at $\sqrt{2}-1$, where $x^2+y^2=3-2\sqrt{2}$.

Also, $x^2+y^2$ is maximum when $y$ is minimum, at $-1-\sqrt{2}$, where $x^2+y^2=3+2\sqrt{2}$.

As $r=|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, we have that if $r\in \left[\sqrt{3-2\sqrt{2}},\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{2}}\right]$ there is a complex number satisfying our desired property (because the norm is continuous and thus its image on the connected circle must be the whole interval).

If $|z-i|^2 -2=0$ the procedure is analogous and is left to the reader.